# .htaccess files not working in php website

Tags: .htaccess

I have .htaccess file with this below code that time website showing with one error message 500 internal server error.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.website.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

When I renamed to .htaccess file that time it not showing any error it is working fine. I am using 1and1 server windows control panel.

I given file permissions to folders '0755' and for files '0644' and for .htaccess file '604'.

where I did mistake. please suggest me.

Comment: but my website is not working means It showing 500 internal server error.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? to make it so that the file extension doesn't appear?